# Avoid Current Culture in ToString(..)

Tags: .net, localization, tostring

I need to format decimal value as per display format specified. `"decimalValue.ToString("##,##,##,##,##,##,###")"` in code below is considering the current application culture internally and formatting value accordingly.

I tried CulutreInfo.InvariantCulture - didn't help because 
"NumberFormat.CurrencyGroupSizes" of InvariantCulture is set to 3 and is considering that while formatting the value.

I need to avoid it, i should be able to tell application ingore culture and just format value as per displayformat specified.

Any solution ? please help.

e.g.

```
 decimal? de = 1234567890;
 string displayFormat = "##,##,##,##,##,##,###";
 string result = de.Value.ToString(displayFormat);
 System.Console.WriteLine(result);
```

o/p - 1,234,567,890
(Application culture is en-US).

Comment: Which language? `tostring` is not a really useful tag!

Comment: @deepakr, are you sure "##,##,##,##,##,##,###" is a legal format string for a decimal number? @felix, obviously .NET. :)

Comment: @bzlm: Maybe obvious for people who know .NET ;)

Comment: @bzlm - it is for currency and specifying the format is up to end user.

Comment: @deepakr, but does that format string actually work?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
decimal? de = 1234567890;
string displayFormat = "##/##/##/##/##/##/###";
string result = de.Value.ToString(displayFormat).Replace("/", ",").TrimStart(new char[] { ',' } );
System.Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Comment: Trick is good :) but if the application culture's "NumberFormat.CurrencyDecimalSeparator" is set to "/" then nothing works. I know it is rare such things happens, but solution shouldn't introduce one more issue. agree ?

Comment: I think you mean `CurrencyGroupSeparator` in which case: `if (Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.CurrencyGroupSeparator == "/") //just use the comma as intended

Comment: Can we override the 'CurrencyGroupSizes' of current culture by implementing IFormatProvider according to group size in display format ?

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.Globalization;

void Main()
{
    CultureInfo myCIintl = new CultureInfo( "hi-IN", false );
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = myCIintl;
    double de = 1234567890;
    Console.WriteLine(de.ToString("c"));
}
```

Comment: i am not sure whether you understood my question ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want Indian number/date formating then the code shared by shahkalpesh is valid (however you don't need to change the culture of the thread, you can directly set it in `String.Format(IFormatProvider, String, Object[])` method)

If however you want to create your own custom culture, consider using `CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder` to define it.